# Importing modules -ascustomobject and module parameters in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, dependency-injection, module

Given the following modules:

adonetlib.psml

```
param($ModelModule)

$dbmodel=import-module $ModelModule -AsCustomObject 

function new-ADOnetconnection{
   return $dbmodel.newconnection()
}
```

mysqlmodel.psm1

```
function newconnection{
   write-host "MySQL connection"
}
```

sqlservermodel.psm1

```
function newconnection{
   write-host "SQLServer connection"
}
```

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
$mysql= import-module adonetlib -argumentlist mysqlmodel -ascustomobject
$sqlserver= import-module adonetlib -argumentlist sqlservermodel -ascustomobject
```

and have the following be true (sorry about the syntax):

```
$mysql."new-adonetconnection"() -> returns "MySql connection"
$sqlsever."new-adonetconnection"() -> returns "SQLServer connection"
```

Apparently, though, the adonetlib module is only loaded once (even though we imported it with different arguments).  Both statements return "MySQL connection".

Also,

```
get-module -all
```

shows that the mysqlmodel module is loaded, but sqlservermodel isn't.

Any ideas about how I can get this to work?

Comment: Might have found an easy answer.  Adding -force to the import-module commands seems to do the trick.  I was also thinking about using new-module to return "custom" modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you're looking for may be present already in the [Powershell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/):

```
PS C:\Users\davidp> Get-command -Module pscx | ? { $_ -like "*-ado*" } | select name

Name
----
Get-ADObject
Get-AdoConnection
Get-AdoDataProvider
Invoke-AdoCommand
```

But in case you're implementing just for fun:

You might be better off using submodules to implement the polymorphic behavior it looks like you're trying to achieve.  The top-level module would export a single New-ADOnetConnection cmdlet, with a parameter to select which DB you want to use for that connection; then it would dynamically choose which submodule to use to carry out the command.

If you'd like to avoid having to specify the DB on every call, you could create your own preference variable.

Comment: don't know how I've missed those commands in PSCX.  I've been using it since I first started with PowerShell.  This is something I'm working on for SQLPSX, and will probably be more involved than what is in PSCX.  As far as submodules go, I'd really like the DB-specific stuff to be separate (for deployment reasons).  I can see having dozens of different DBs for this, and I don't want everyone to need all of them if they're only using a few.

Comment: Proxy functions might be a better idea for your specific use case Mike.  Then you could make a decision about which command to run.

Comment: I'm familiar with proxy functions, but I don't see exactly what you mean.  Could you perhaps expand this in an answer (pseudo-code is fine)?

Comment: @David...you set me down the right road.  I dug into the code of PSCX, and I was apparently re-inventing ADO.NET dbFactory classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try Import-Module *-Force* in your script. For some reason, the command doesn't replace any previous import without it

> -Force
>       Re-imports a module and its members, even if the module or its members have an access mode of read-only.

Edit: Sorry, missed the comment above. No intention of "stealing" the answer ;)

Comment: No worries.  I'm just looking for ideas as far as how to implement this.